# How to adapt startManagingCursor() to a non-deprecated method?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, deprecation-warning

I've been trying to stick with `startManagingCursor()` for my read-only SQLite database, but it's throwing a lot of errors even if I use `stopManagingCursor()` (yes, I know [they're deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startManagingCursor(android.database.Cursor))).

I'd like to have some help to know the steps to go from managing cursors to a better method without changing much since I've never used them and this code is somehow stable although random errors pop up from time to time because of `startManagingCursor()` (in a single activity app, it works fine, but when using it as a frament in a multifragment app, it gets really problematic).

However, when I simply change `startManagingCursor()` to `getLoaderManager()` it still works, but [the documentation also tells it's deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getLoaderManager()) and indicates `getSupportLoaderManager()` and, when I use this one, it gets crossed out as if it's also deprecated (Lint says "`getSupportLoaderManager()` is deprecated", but doesn't say the same for `getLoaderManager()`); and those may produce `java.lang.NullPointerException` what wasn't happening with `startManagingCursor(cursor)` although both are runnable.

So what should I do then?

The SQLite fragment is this:

```
public class SQLiteDatabaseActivity extends Fragment {

    public static SQLiteDatabaseActivity newInstance() {
        return new SQLiteDatabaseActivity();
    }

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    Database mDatabase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sqlite_database_activity, container, false);

        mDatabase = new Database(getActivity());
        mDatabase.open();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase();
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] groupFrom = {
                Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1,
                Database.DATABASE_GROUP_2,
                Database.DATABASE_GROUP_3,
                Database.DATABASE_GROUP_4
        };

        int[] groupTo = {
                R.id.group_number,
                R.id.group_name,
                R.id.group_path,
                R.id.group_company
        };

        String[] childFrom = new String[]{
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_4,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_5,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_6,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_7,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_8,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_9,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_10,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_11,
                Database.DATABASE_CHILD_12
        };

        int[] childTo = {
                R.id.child1,
                R.id.child2,
                R.id.child_saturday_origin,
                R.id.child_saturday_destiny,
                R.id.child_sunday_origin,
                R.id.child_sunday_destiny,
                R.id.child_origin,
                R.id.child_destiny,
                R.id.child_saturday_origin_origin,
                R.id.child_saturday_destiny_destiny,
                R.id.child_sunday_origin_origin,
                R.id.child_sunday_destiny_destiny
        };

        SimpleCursorTreeAdapter simplecursortreeAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                cursor,
                R.layout.sqlite_database_list_group,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                R.layout.sqlite_database_list_child,
                childFrom,
                childTo
        );

        expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListview);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(simplecursortreeAdapter);

        getActivity().stopManagingCursor(cursor);

        return view;
    }

    private class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        private ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                Context context,
                Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout,
                String[] groupFrom,
                int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout,
                String[] childFrom,
                int[] childTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        }

        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            return mDatabase.getID(groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_ID)));
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

The database is here:

```
public class Database {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BusScheduleDatabase.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "BusSchedule";
    public static final String DATABASE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_1 = "Linha";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_2 = "Nome";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_3 = "Caminho";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_4 = "Empresa";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_1 = "SemanaIda";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_2 = "SemanaVolta";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_3 = "SabadoIda";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_4 = "SabadoVolta";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_5 = "DomingoIda";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_6 = "DomingoVolta";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_7 = "Origem";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_8 = "Destino";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_9 = "Origem";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_10 = "Destino";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_11 = "Origem";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_12 = "Destino";

    private final Context mContext;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public Database(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void open() {
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mDB = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDatabaseHelper != null) mDatabaseHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getDatabase() {
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, DATABASE_GROUP_1);
    }

    public Cursor getID(long rowID) {
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "_id" + " = "
                + rowID, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context mContext, String DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int DATABASE_VERSION) {
            super(mContext, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
            super.setForcedUpgrade();
        }
    }

}
```

And the repetitive error is basically the following:

- > java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: If you want to stick with the `Loader` framework, the very newest version in the androidx libraries shouldn't be deprecated, I would think, as they've rewritten it to be a wrapper around the new `ViewModel`/`Observer` architecture components. If you're not familiar with androidx yet, it's basically just the next version of the support libraries, but with some package refactoring and other overall improvements. There's an overview and relevant links on [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/).

Comment: @MikeM., I just can thank you again! Your words are always a good guide and I'll study the content you brought here. I'm still not familiar with AndroidX, but I'll see what can be done with that. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all. I really should mention, though, that the `ViewModel`/`LiveData`/`Observer` stuff is the current "shiny new thing" in Android, and many would recommend that you implement all of that yourself. ([General overview and guide for that here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).) However, for relatively simple projects, and those that may not need a lot of testing, it can be huge overkill. IMO, `Loader`s are great, for the things that they can manage, so if your project is working as you like with those, I see no problem in sticking with 'em. Cheers!

Comment: I agree and I read many suggestions about this new way to deal with it, but I'm not that well versed so it isn't easy to go from here to there without much study, effort and time. I'd like to stick with it because it's a read-only list of schedules with 25 groups with 8 items each. The database was hard enough to put together and now I just want it doesn't break. Changing `startManagingCursor` and closing `onPause` made it really better, but it needs more tests (many groups opened seems to be a problem). AndroidX might help to use a method that isn't deprecated and doesn't throw an exception.